# How to generate exe's and bundle files along in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, exe

Say I have a couple of files like "pic1.jpg" which needs to go to 'My Pictures,' and 'random.exe,' which needs to be placed in local app data folder and then executed with some flags.

What classes should I be looking up on MSDN that can generate an exe and more importantly, how do I 'bundle' with the exe that is going to be generated?

Normally it's easy enough - just add them as resources to the project. But is it as easy to do that for the dynamically generated .exe? (The input files will be different every time)

So, to recap, I need a files-to-exe converter, a bit like an installer minus all the bells and whistles. How can I get started?

Comment: I assume you're not using Visual Studio?  Visual Studio creates an .EXE for you, and it has a Resources section within which you can place your... things, like pictures and icons.  If you need something more sophisticated than this, you can create a Windows Installer project in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want an installer - you can use [InnoSetup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) to create an installer to bundle your files from your project together. This includes installing your main .exe and any dependency that it may have (images, setting files, etc.)

InnoSetup is free to use and is a pretty good installer. There aren't any bells & whistles unless you add them and it handles various special folders for you. (Archivers like WinRar or 7zip could produce a compressed .exe archive for you but they don't handle different target folders for different files in the archive very well (or at all).)

PS: let me know if I misunderstood your question.

**Edit**:

Look at [`AssemblyBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/99ab870x%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to start with generating assemblies on the fly. You'll have to generate all methods yourself by emitting IL opcodes with the right parameters and then save your assembly to disk when you're done.

In general, the entire [`System.Reflection.Emit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xd5fw18y%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) namespace is what you should look at. You can also try using [Mono.Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) to generate assemblies - this simplifies a lot of things you need to do but it has its own quirks that you'll have to learn.

This question may be useful to you:
[Generate exe in .Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2601198/generate-exe-in-net)

Comment: That is in essence what I want to do. However, I want to learn how to do it myself, that's why I asked for classes on how to generate an executable rather than just asking for an installer IDE :)